# Magento 2.2.2 return only 3 items from wishlist

Tags: magento2.2.2, wishlist, local-storage

When inspecting the bellow

> console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mage-cache-storage')).wishlist);

I get the count of 7 but items only returns 3 :

[image]

How Can one get all items ? in my case 7 ? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

As Magento had set limit in class `Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist` `const SIDEBAR_ITEMS_NUMBER = 3;`

So if you want to increase limit of product you have to override this class and set your custom limit as per your requirement.

Comment: I can see `
     * @var string
     */
    const SIDEBAR_ITEMS_NUMBER = 5;`
But it doesn't work I've run `setup:upgrade & php bin/magento cache:clean & php bin/magento cache:flush`  Clear my browser cache an still 3 on side and in the locastorage saying that I don't want to change how many it shows I want to get total for specific customer  I've run sql :`SELECT * FROM wishlist_item INNER JOIN wishlist ON wishlist_item.wishlist_id = wishlist.wishlist_id;`   it gives everything don't want to create module just to fetch this is there a way for this with ko compoment etc...?

Comment: After changing CONST value log out and log in again then check does it work or not.

Comment: @arvesh Ahuja  indeed  once log out and log in again it does. How about      getting all items for specific customer with ko component javascript ajax etc... ?without changing this value like: `SELECT * FROM wishlist_item INNER JOIN wishlist ON wishlist_item.wishlist_id = wishlist.wishlist_id AND wishlist.customer_id = int;`

Comment: It can be possible but as per your question you can change count of items as per my solution or if you want total then you can override "getItems()" function and remove "setPageSize(self::SIDEBAR_ITEMS_NUMBER)" from collection of items. :)

Comment: I understand but no exactly what I am looking for as you may have already figured it out :) thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Keep helping! :)

Answer (score 0):

> Once you need to extend `\Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist`
>   class into your module then try this code.

```
    protected function getItems()
    {
        $this->view->loadLayout();

        $collection = $this->wishlistHelper->getWishlistItemCollection();
        $collection->clear()->setPageSize(self::SIDEBAR_ITEMS_NUMBER)
            ->setInStockFilter(true)->setOrder('added_at');

        $items = [];
        foreach ($collection as $wishlistItem) {
            $items[] = $this->getItemData($wishlistItem);
        }
        return $items;
    }
```

> Remove this `->setPageSize(self::SIDEBAR_ITEMS_NUMBER)` from above
>   code you will get total number of wishlist products.
>
> Because `const SIDEBAR_ITEMS_NUMBER = 3;` is set that is why you are
>   getting only 3 products.